# No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, anaconda3

I am using Anaconda Python 3.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

but Python does not recognize the Numpy. I appreciate your help.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4266db17a4ae> in <module>
      1 # Importing the libraries
----> 2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

​

Comment: is numpy installed in your conda environment? verify it with conda list -n your-env

Comment: Hi Sardar, thanks a lot. yes I have installed everything   (base) C:\Users\rquir>conda install -c anaconda numpy
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.


(base) C:\Users\rquir>